# How to get the last event when use jquery event delegate

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, delegates

[This is my jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qnnck7Le/1/). When i click the `anothermenu` link, I want to remove the css class `selected` before. I have tried the following jQuery code

```
$(function(){
    $("#menuBar").on("click", "a", function() {
        $(".menu").children().removeClass("selected");
        $(this).parent().addClass("selected");
    });
})
```

It can solve my problem. But i think is ugly. Any has some tidy solutions?

Answer (score 1):

The logic is fine. All you can really do to improve this is to make it a one-liner by using `siblings()` instead of creating a new selector for the removal of the `selected` class:

```
$("#menuBar").on("click", "a", function () { 
    $(this).parent().addClass("selected").siblings().removeClass('selected');
});
```

[**Updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/qnnck7Le/2/)

Comment: I have tried the siblings. But it has problem.  When i click the `anothermenu`, the css class on `menu or menu1 or menu2` will not be removed.